# step by step process to create BI publisher reporting using xml bursting?

Tags: xml, oracle, rtf, bi-publisher, oracle-apps

STEPS TO MAKE XML BURSTING REPORT

Number of files / steps required :
1.  SQL package which includes declaration of variables and concurrent request capture logic in order to  make concurrent program.

2. file which generates xml output (data template) which is to be treated as input for rtf .
3. xml Bursting file which contains xml encoding of mail deligators and column names to be reflected in PDF OUTPUT file.
4. RTF file which contains design of the PDF output to be generated.

   ```
      5.   Define the concurrent programme :
   ```
5. define executable for the same concurrent program :

   ```
   7.    On DEV instance we need to design DATA DEFINATION and DATA template through interfaces:
          steps :
         Responsibility : XML PUBLISHER ADMINISTRATOR >> HOME >> DATA DEFINATION
   ```

DATA DEFINATION DETAILS :
CODE : XXXXX ( should be same as the concurrent program’s short name)

on the same DATA DEFINATION window DO the Following UPLOADS:

•   Upload the DATA template  ( example: xxxxx.XML)- data template file name should be same as of short  name of concurrent program
•   Upload the BURSTING CONTROL FILE ( Example : xxxxx.xml(dev))

8. click on TEMPLATE tab to create template :

Fill the details accordingly and Upload the rtf file :

NOTE : we can also create DATA template through single package only without uploading any file as data template from front end.

NOTE 2:  Define theb concurrent program with 
executable NAME : xxxxx
method : PL SQL PROCEDURE

Comment: This is not a question

Comment: Agreed. Not a question.